# "sudo service uwsgi restart" returns [fail] however uwsgi logs show processes have been created and python app is running

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm running a local vagrant VM, Ubuntu 13.10 with nginx reverse proxying to uwsgi.

Running

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx status
```

returns

```
* nginx is running
```

However running

```
sudo /etc/init.d/uwsgi status
```

returns

```
* which one?
```

If I take a look at the log file for the wsgi app I can see that uwsgi is running, worker processes have been created etc... so is there a hidden instance of uwsgi running somewhere that's confusing the service restart command?

I installed uwsgi using:

```
apt-get install uwsgi
```

Here's the app.ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
plugin = python
socket  = /run/uwsgi/app/myapp/socket
chdir = /var/www/myapp
module = project.wsgi:application
pidfile = /tmp/myapp-master.pid
master = True
daemonize = /var/log/uwsgi/myapp.log
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Same issue Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) with `1.9.17.1-debian`. This has to be a bug, but I don't know if it belongs to the people behind the Ubuntu repository, or to uwsgi.

Comment: In any case, I just install with PIP instead. PIP does not install it as a service, so I create /etc/init/uwsgi.conf myself. The startup files are much much easier to read and understand (and write) which is another bonus.

Comment: Just a guess: by default 4 processes with name "uwsgi" are created, and service script can not choose from them by name.
Earlier the main process of uwsgi was named uwsgi-emperor but now they are confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changing the pidfile option to pidfile2 seems to fix this issue.

```
pidfile2 = /tmp/myapp-master.pid
```

Interestingly the `service uwsgi stop` returns `[OK]` but the `service uwsgi start` returns `[fail]`

So I'm assuming the error happens when a non privileged user (i.e. www-data) is trying to write to the pidfile which has been created by a privileged user (e.g. root).

pidfile2 will create the pidfile after privileges drop - so www-data can happily write to it.

If someone else can shed light on whether this is the case that would be great.

Comment: Had the same problem, renaming pidfile worked. Link to documentation, for reference:
http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#pidfile2

Comment: does not fix... all priveleges are done, but service can not choose from multiple instances